# Docker nginx not starting after running custom script

Tags: docker, nginx

We have an angular app we are trying to run in docker nginx.
I have to run a script on startup that uses an environment variableto replace the app url for each stage. This is needed to connect to the backend.
We do not wish to build the container for each stage. The container will run in Azure docker.
For now i am running it locally. It executes my script and then the app shuts down.

The Docker File:

```
FROM node:8.11.2-alpine as node
LABEL author="My Online Presence"
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine
COPY /certificates /etc/nginx/
COPY --from=node /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 
ADD run.sh /usr/share/nginx/html/run.sh

RUN apk add --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/nginx/html/run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/share/nginx/html/run.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The run.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE_NAME=$(find . -name "main*.js")
sed -i "s/localhost\:4200/${DIGITISE_URL}/g" $FILE_NAME
echo 'File updated with correct url'
```

i use

```
docker build -t digitise .
```

and then

```
docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -e DIGITISE_URL=digitise.co.za digitise
```

Comment: Docker runs the `ENTRYPOINT` only, and when the `ENTRYPOINT` exits, the container exits too.  Your script will get the `CMD` passed as arguments.

Comment: so how can i change it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working simply by adding

```
exec "$@"
```

to the end of my script being run

Answer (score 0):

You can also start nginx service in your script.